# How to change font to Helvetica with par3d for a pca3d plot

Tags: r, plot, 3d, font-family

I'm trying to change the font to Helvetica in a plot I generate with pca3d. I tried defining it in the par3d like this

```
par3d(family= "Helvetica", cex=2)
```

but I get this error

```
Warning messages:
1: In par3d(family = "Helvetica", cex = 2) :
font family "Helvetica" not found, using "bitmap"
2: In par3d(family = "Helvetica", cex = 2) :
"bitmap" family only supports cex = 1
```

I am not sure where it uses the fonts from, but I checked the X11fonts and pdfFonts in my system and I have the Helvetica font.

I also tried to change the defaults first and then set the par3d

```
r3dDefaults$family = "Helvetica"
par3d(family= "Helvetica", cex=2)
```

but I still get the exact same error.

Any thoughts on how I can change the font to Helvetica for a pca3d plot, using either pca3d or anything else? Thanks!

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using Mac OS El Capitan (10.11.6).

Comment: Take a look at this [R-Bloggers Post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/changing-the-font-of-r-base-graphic-plots/)

Comment: I searched the FontBook for the exact Helvetica names and ran `quartzFonts(helvetica = c("Helvetica Light", "Helvetica Bold", "Helvetica Light Oblique", "Helvetica Bold Oblique"))` and then `par3d(family= "helvetica")` , but I get the exact same error as before. BUT when I do `par(family="helvetica")` it works. It's related to the 3d, any ideas how to solve this?